# Develop Vert.x App

Tags: vert.x

I'm writting a Http server using Vert.x 3.0 and this server will listen at certain port for example at port 8080. But as I read in documentation which say that Vert.x thread will not be stopped even when main thread is terminated. So next time when I debug app, port 8080 is used and I must deploy server at another port
My question is: How I can develop Vert.x app without changing port everytime?

Comment: Could you provide some code please? How are you deploying your verticles and what the main verticle sources look like?

Comment: Can you kill java process in task manager manually? Or use ```netstat -ano | grep PORT``` to see which ```pid``` uses that port and kill it in task manager?

Answer (score 1):

I have never had problems with Vert.x thread staying alive on a port after I kill the JVM.  If you use linux just hit 'control-c" in the terminal. It works for me.  something similar would also work in mac and windows (I suppose).  This should not be a problem at all when developing in vert.x